# configuring Emacs as a client for pylsp server

Tags: python-3.x, emacs, python-language-server

I'd like to try to use Emacs as an LSP client for a Python project (pylsp server, [here](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server))

I'd like an example about how to configure emacs for such a thing

IN particular, I'm interested in how to let Emacs instruct pylsp about where some libraries are

Comment: pylsp generally need to be installed in the same environment as your project so that it can find the libraries for your project. Basically, you need to run pylsp with a Python that can import both pylsp and the project's dependencies from the same interpreter, and it'll handle the rest for you.